# What is this in my /var/sys/syslog

Tags: syslog

```
Oct  1 13:17:01 tilaprimera /USR/SBIN/CRON[5710]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a background task scheduler named `cron` that runs tasks at specific times.

The log entry you see in `syslog` is the cron daemon running its hourly tasks.

`run-parts` is a utility to run executables in a directory. Hence

```
run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

runs all executable files in the directory `/etc/cron.hourly`

Take a look at `/etc/crontab`. There is an entry

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

telling to run the command in question at 17 minutes past every hour.

For more details see the [man-page of `run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/run-parts.8.html) and [`crontab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html)

Comment: Is this a legit cron kept by the system ? Can I disable it or something?

Comment: @tilaprimera Yes, perfectly legit. Of course you could disable it by commenting out the line in `crontab`, but I see no reason why. Nothing is run now anyways and chances are some service might need the hourly cronjobs in the future.